# Integral over the Adjoint Map

Tags: lie-algebras

$\newcommand{\ad}{\operatorname{ad}}$
Let $\ad_X\in \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{g})$ be the adjoint map for arbitrary but fixed $X\in\mathfrak{g}$. Denote with $C_{\mathfrak{g}}(X)$ the centraliser of $X$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.

Consider the following expression, with $\mathfrak{g}=su(N)$: $$\int_0^te^{sX}Ae^{-sX}\,ds=\int_0^t\exp(s\,\ad_X)A\,\mathrm ds,\quad A\in su(N).$$

I've been wondering if there is a way to perform the integral and noticed that $$[\exp(t \ad_X)\ad_X^{-1}-\ad_X^{-1}]A$$ should do the job when $\ad_X^{-1}$ exists. Clearly this is not the case for the whole algebra, but is it true if we restrict the domain of $\ad_X$ to $su(N)\setminus C_{su(N)}(X)$, and accordingly $A\in su(N)\setminus C_{su(N)}(X)$?

Comment: This is a [standard result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_integral_formula). In fact the inverse of the adjoint map you are looking at vanishes to yield a celebrated function of ad$_X$ related to Bernouli numbers. it is routinely used in physics. You want more?

Comment: Cheers! I checked the BCH formula but must have overlooked this part somehow...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Actually, would you mind to show how the above formula emerges from the one you linked to?

Comment: You want something beyond the formal Taylor series expansion in *t* , *s* around 0?

Comment: Well, if I expand and perform the integral, is there a way I can rewrite the infinite sum into sth like the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ad}{\operatorname{ad}}$
OK,   just represent your function as the Taylor series in *t* around zero, the [standard result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map), 
$$[\exp(t \ad_X)\ad_X^{-1}-\ad_X^{-1}]A =t \phi (t \ad_X) ,$$
where 
$$
\phi(x)\equiv \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!} =\int_0^{t}\!\!ds ~~e^{sx}.
$$
I'm not sure what it is that you are after.